# 1993 Apple Color Classic

Tags: mac, power, color

Lets all take a long journey back about 21 years ago when apple released their color classic. It was pretty awesome right? Well I managed to get my hands on one but I have some sad news.

When I go to power on my wonderful dinosaur I get nothing. And by nothing I mean, no fan spinning, no lights, no hard-drive POST-ing.

Could anyone give me a hint to as what is wrong with my Mac.

### My idea is

-3.6 Volt  battery is dead

-Power supply is shot

ALSO, I do not have a keyboard or mouse connected, but I do not think that, that would cause the fan to no start.

Any help or suggestions would be fantastic.Thanks all!

Comment: Hate to break it to you, but the first color Mac was far from Apple's first color pc. The Apple // had color, and the //GS had not only color but GSOS provided a color version of the Finder years before Mac supported it. #AppleTwoForever

Comment: @DanielLawson oh my! I don't my history as much as I would hope. My Bad. Will change!

Comment: @DanielLawson, Apple II was stylized `Apple ][`, and Apple IIGS as `Apple IIɢs`. Only `Apple //e` was stylized with the two forward slashes if I recall correctly.

Comment: Your suggestions are good. I thought the battery did not matter for booting, but I was wrong and a dead battery means no boot. Thanks [@SteveChambers](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/145402/55028)

Answer (score 6):

Our "Cousin" has a number of good suggestions.

The "BIOS" which is just the firmware of the machine and not strictly speaking a BIOS needs to be there and non-corrupt just like he said.

You do need a battery and it needs to be good, it won't boot without it. That is what I would replace first. Just pop it out of the machine and take it to a batteries+ store or some such near you. They can test it, if it's good there are other (potentially more serious) issues. If it is bad, buy a new one.

Once installed just try switching it on.

If it is STILL not working it could be a bad power supply or any one of a hundred (literally...) other things. And depending on how much money you want to spend and how good you are with a multi-meter and some Googling for sites with repair info, you might get it up and running.

**JUST ONE THING THOUGH** It is **very important** to be **very careful** working in one of the all-in-one Macs with a built-in CRT like the Color Classic.

There will be a big red wire going into a rubber "boot" attached to the back side of the CRT. **Stay away from that,** there can be enough residual voltage stored in that tube to kill you. And no I am not exaggerating or just trying to scare you. Stay away from that wire, especially where it connects to the tube and the other end in the power supply. I have worked on a lot of old style all-in-one Macs and you **can** safely work in them. Just be careful and stay far away from that wire.

If a new battery did not do the trick, I would disassemble it: Motherboard, drives, RAM, etc. (but stay away from the high voltage power supply and the big red wire. Clean contacts and look for capacitors that have swelled up, broken wires or scorch marks. Re-assemble and try again.

That should at least get you started...

Comment: Good post and needs to be on top.

Comment: I have ordered a new battery, should be here in a few days. I'll keep you posted. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 3):

You ask for suggestions, not clear answers. I still have a working Classic, but the color version is pretty similar.

Ok, this is my € 0,02.

Just speculating, just like you ask.

You expect a BEEP when you turn it on. No beep means no bios. You expect at least a [happy mac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh_startup#Happy_Mac), or a [sad mac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh_startup#Sad_Mac).

No bios because:

- no power
- corrupt bios
- dead battery

No power can be possible due to more things:

- fuse (do not know if it is in there, but I think there is one)
- wrong power supply (230 volts/50Hz vs. 110 volts/60Hz)
- broken power switch

What it is probably not:

- harddrive: Would give a bomb or a sad mac sign or a question mark. And you do not need your harddrive to boot, an OS 6 system floppy would be enough.
- <s>bios/PRAM battery. The battery is not needed to boot, the battery only helps to store the preferences/settings.</s> (edit: this was complete bogus)

Comment: Open her, start measuring with a multimeter.

Comment: I believe I have a corrupt bios. Do you have any clue how to reimage the bios or reset it?

Comment: I have no clue. My guess is you need to solder a new one in or upload it's software by hacking some wires to a com port. Sorry. If you really want to know, contact [Steve Wozniak](https://twitter.com/stevewoz), he knows for sure ;)

Comment: How on earth am I going to get another bios chip or even the files! Looks like it is just a huge paper weight...

Comment: As I said. I have no clue. But try like llange says, replace the battery first.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with FatMac and MacPlus :

As you said test the battery because it can affect startup. Normally it's has been the same kind of battery for the whole 90s Mac (from Classic to G4 QuickSilver).

Then most issues related to Power On Self Test (POST) ar RAM related (you need 3 things for a Mac to "work" (power, motherboard, RAM).

As Steve Chambers tells you beware while dissambling because it's a CRT screen...
Check that power jumpers are on the right position (220V or 110V)...
Nevertheless for electronic component use appropriate ESD equipment (ground your self).

http://www.techrepublic.com/pictures/cracking-open-the-apple-macintosh-classic/1/